# How can I extend/subclass Array so that it indexes its items?

Tags: ios, swift

In the current version of Swift, the method `indexOf` is apparently linear time.  This makes it pretty much useless if my array is large and I need to call `indexOf` frequently.  How can we subclass `Array` so that:

- Every time we insert an element, the array auto-magically indexes it in a hash map
- Every time we remove an element, it removes it from the index
- When we try to find the element later, it's returned immediately

I want to use this array for UITableView. I thought about using a dictionary, but

- Is the ordering kept?
- Can I get the object, given the index?
- If I retrieve the object at a given index, will it be linear time or constant time?

I simply want to use a fixed, constant-time version of `Array.indexOf`.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga This will be my data source for my UITableView.  If I use a dictionary, is it possible to lookup by the index? ```let item = myDict[row]``` And is it kept in order?

Comment: Yes, you can lookup by "key" (maybe use the index as key), and no, dictionaries does not have order

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga if it's not ordered, then I can't use it for UITableView, since I need to look up ordered rows all the time.

Comment: I see.. maybe you can use a "custom key" (e.g. index+key, like "0mykey", "1otherKey").., and then retrieve the index part.. ugly, but might work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't subclass Array. Create a new class that has both an Array and a Dictionary as instance variables. Use the array for ordering and the dictionary to map from item to array index. You'll have to write your own routines for insertion, lookup, and deletion. If you use generic types for the key and value the class will be useful in other projects in the future. I did this a few years ago (without generics) in an Objective-C project.

The more I think about it, though, the more I think you should use a tree instead, because if you insert or remove items from the middle of the array your dictionary indices will be off. A tree structure will preserve both order and allow for reasonably fast lookup.

Comment: I haven't used this one, but it's worth looking into: https://github.com/lorentey/BTree

Comment: Can't subclass array because it's `Struct`!